# InterfaceError unknown type <class 'decimal.Decimal'> for arg 10

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to fetch some data from my database., this works perfect on my local machine. But when deployed on Google App Engine it gives me an error

> InterfaceError at /report/unit/D8500/WV_herverkoop/2013/0/10/
>   unknown type <class 'decimal.Decimal'> for arg 10

**full traceback**

```
    InterfaceError at /report/unit/D8500/WV_herverkoop/2013/0/10/
unknown type <class 'decimal.Decimal'> for arg 10
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://dw-services.appspot.com/report/unit/D8500/WV_herverkoop/2013/0/10/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: InterfaceError
Exception Value:    
unknown type <class 'decimal.Decimal'> for arg 10
Exception Location: /python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py in _AddBindVariablesToRequest, line 427
Python Executable:  /python27_runtime/python27_dist/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/base/data/home/apps/s~dw-services/2.365787501016750085',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
 '/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10',
 '/base/data/home/apps/s~dw-services/2.365787501016750085/..']
Server time:    don, 7 Mrt 2013 13:58:28 +0000
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/base/data/home/apps/s~dw-services/2.365787501016750085/dewaelereports/views/reportView.py in showReportPerOffice
        position = 0           # position in which we'll insert the region
        region_commission = 0  # commission earned in a region
        region_count = 0       # transactions in a region
        region_avg = 0         # average in a region
        counter = 0            # detect when it's the first zip in the region
        for zip in region.zips.all():
            results = zip.get_total_sales(office, start_week, end_week, year, unit_type) ...
            total_count += results[0][0]
            total_commission += results[0][1]
            region_count += results[0][0]
            region_commission += results[0][1]
            zipList.append((zip.zip_name, results[0], results[1]))
            if counter == 0:
▶ Local vars
/base/data/home/apps/s~dw-services/2.365787501016750085/dewaelereports/models.py in get_total_sales
        return [calculate_results(zip_transactions, unit), zip_transactions] ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
office  
<Office: D8500>
transactions    
[<Transaction: k08071>, <Transaction: T8500-08157C>, <Transaction: D8500-11451>, <Transaction: D8500-12042H>, <Transaction: D8500-12143B>, <Transaction: T8500-09259>, <Transaction: T8500-10244a>, <Transaction: T8500-10277>, <Transaction: T8500-10277>, <Transaction: D8500-10345-A12>, <Transaction: T8500-10420>, <Transaction: T8500-10496>, <Transaction: T8500-11040H>, <Transaction: D8500-11048>, <Transaction: D8500-11650H>, <Transaction: D8500-11255B>, <Transaction: T8500-11325>, <Transaction: D8500-11343H>, <Transaction: T8500-11497>, <Transaction: D8500-11508B>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
start_week  
u'0'
self    
<Zip: 8500 - Kortrijk>
zip_transactions    
[<Office_per_transaction: 2460>, <Office_per_transaction: 2413>, <Office_per_transaction: 775>, <Office_per_transaction: 2477>, <Office_per_transaction: 2414>, <Office_per_transaction: 2485>]
unit    
<Unit_type: WV herverkoop>
year    
u'2013'
office_transactions 
[<Office_per_transaction: 196>, <Office_per_transaction: 1111>, <Office_per_transaction: 2460>, <Office_per_transaction: 2433>, <Office_per_transaction: 1105>, <Office_per_transaction: 1135>, <Office_per_transaction: 2413>, <Office_per_transaction: 775>, <Office_per_transaction: 3176>, <Office_per_transaction: 3444>, <Office_per_transaction: 2477>, <Office_per_transaction: 2414>, <Office_per_transaction: 1094>, <Office_per_transaction: 2485>]
end_week    
u'10'
/base/data/home/apps/s~dw-services/2.365787501016750085/dewaelereports/models.py in calculate_results
    if len(transaction_query) >= 1:
        sum = 0
        for tr in transaction_query:
            sum += tr.transaction.commission_fix_out * (tr.office_percentage / 100)
        if unit:
            if unit.min_quantity:
                count_transactions = len(transaction_query.filter(transaction__transaction_price_out__gt=str(unit.min_quantity))) ...
        if not unit or not unit.min_quantity:
            count_transactions = len(transaction_query)
        avg = sum / len(transaction_query)
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
transaction_query   
[<Office_per_transaction: 2460>, <Office_per_transaction: 2413>, <Office_per_transaction: 775>, <Office_per_transaction: 2477>, <Office_per_transaction: 2414>, <Office_per_transaction: 2485>]
count_transactions  
0
sum 
Decimal('61313.0300')
tr  
<Office_per_transaction: 2485>
avg 
0
unit    
<Unit_type: WV herverkoop>
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/models/query.py in __len__
                self._result_cache = list(self.iterator()) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/models/query.py in iterator
        for row in compiler.results_iter(): ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in results_iter
        for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI): ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/backends/util.py in execute
            return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py in execute
            return self.cursor.execute(query, args) ...
▶ Local vars
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py in execute
    request = sql_pb2.ExecRequest()
    request.options.include_generated_keys = True
    if args is not None:
      if not hasattr(args, '__iter__'):
        args = [args]
      self._AddBindVariablesToRequest(
          statement, args, request.bind_variable.add) ...
    request.statement = _ConvertFormatToQmark(statement, args)
    self._DoExec(request)
    self._executed = request.statement
  def executemany(self, statement, seq_of_args):
    """Prepares and executes a database operation for given parameter sequences.
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
self    
<google.storage.speckle.python.api.rdbms.Cursor object at 0xfc8c0b10>
args    
(1,
 0,
 10,
 '2013-01-01 00:00:00',
 '2013-12-31 23:59:59.99',
 'R',
 'S',
 13,
 2,
 1459,
 Decimal('75000'))
request 
<google.storage.speckle.proto.sql_pb2.ExecRequest object at 0xfc8a6458>
statement   
'SELECT `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_percentage` FROM `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction` INNER JOIN `dewaelereports_transaction` ON (`dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` = `dewaelereports_transaction`.`id`) WHERE (`dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_id` = %s  AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_week` BETWEEN %s and %s AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_date` BETWEEN %s and %s AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_status` IN (%s, %s) AND `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` IN (SELECT U0.`transaction_id` FROM `dewaelereports_transaction_status` U0 WHERE U0.`status` = %s ) AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`unit_type_id` = %s  AND `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `dewaelereports_transaction` U0 INNER JOIN `dewaelereports_property` U1 ON (U0.`premises_id` = U1.`id`) WHERE U1.`property_zip_id` = %s ) AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_price_out` > %s )'
/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/storage/speckle/python/api/rdbms.py in _AddBindVariablesToRequest
          raise InterfaceError('unknown type %s for arg %d' % (type(arg), i)) ...
▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
direction   
1
i   
10
bind_variable_factory   
<bound method RepeatedCompositeFieldContainer.add of [<google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c14c8>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c17a0>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1960>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1998>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1f10>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1dc0>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c17d8>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1c70>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c15a8>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1d50>, <google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1ed8>]>
args    
(1,
 0,
 10,
 '2013-01-01 00:00:00',
 '2013-12-31 23:59:59.99',
 'R',
 'S',
 13,
 2,
 1459,
 Decimal('75000'))
bv  
<google.storage.speckle.proto.client_pb2.BindVariableProto object at 0xfc8c1ed8>
statement   
'SELECT `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id`, `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_percentage` FROM `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction` INNER JOIN `dewaelereports_transaction` ON (`dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` = `dewaelereports_transaction`.`id`) WHERE (`dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`office_id` = %s  AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_week` BETWEEN %s and %s AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_date` BETWEEN %s and %s AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_end_status` IN (%s, %s) AND `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` IN (SELECT U0.`transaction_id` FROM `dewaelereports_transaction_status` U0 WHERE U0.`status` = %s ) AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`unit_type_id` = %s  AND `dewaelereports_office_per_transaction`.`transaction_id` IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `dewaelereports_transaction` U0 INNER JOIN `dewaelereports_property` U1 ON (U0.`premises_id` = U1.`id`) WHERE U1.`property_zip_id` = %s ) AND `dewaelereports_transaction`.`transaction_price_out` > %s )'
arg 
Decimal('75000')
self    
<google.storage.speckle.python.api.rdbms.Cursor object at 0xfc8c0b10>
```

Obviously it fails because it says that `unit.min_quantity` is a decimal. But i didn't declare it as a Decimal in my models:

```
class Unit_type(models.Model):
    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=145)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    min_quantity = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'unit type'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.unit_name
```

When I fill out the statement and execute it manually in Google Cloud Sql, it does work. Can someone help me with this nasty issue?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should put max_digits for min_quantity

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to query Google Cloud SQL using SQLAlchemy with a decimal.Decimal bound parameter.  For example:  `m.ProductPrice.query.filter(m.ProductPrice.volume <= decimal.Decimal('1.23')).all()` raises an InterfaceError.

Comment: A workaround I found is to change the parameter from a Decimal to a str, for example: `m.ProductPrice.query.filter(m.ProductPrice.volume <= str(decimal.Decimal('1.12'))).all()`

Comment: Hi @SeanLynch, i solved my problem by reversing my Transaction object  back to using an IntegerField. (as it was previously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Cloud SQL DBAPI currently does not support the `decimal.Decimal` type, although you can monkey patch it to:

```
import decimal  
from google.storage.speckle.proto import jdbc_type

from google.storage.speckle.python.api import converters  
from google.storage.speckle.python.api import rdbms  
from google.storage.speckle.python.api import rdbms_googleapi

rdbms._PYTHON_TYPE_TO_JDBC_TYPE[decimal.Decimal] = jdbc_type.DECIMAL  
converters.conversions[decimal.Decimal] = converters.Any2Str  
converters.conversions[jdbc_type.DECIMAL] = decimal.Decimal
```

There is an issue logged [here](https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/issues/detail?id=62) where a Google representative provided the patch above and indicated they are working on a fix for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try it out on our testserver later on today.